# More DB connections than Maximum Pool Size

Tags: c#, .net-core, npgsql

In our application (using .NET Core 3.1, Npgsql and PostgreSQL DB), we started getting the following DB exception:

```
Exception data:
    Severity: FATAL
    SqlState: 53300
    MessageText: sorry, too many clients already
    File: proc.c
    Line: 365
    Routine: InitProces
```

When looking at connection analytics of the database, we can sometimes see more than 130 database connections, even though the `Maximum Pool Size` attribute in our connection string is set to 125. Is it possible that Npgsql opens new connections after the maximum pool size is reached? I could not find any explicit documentation to what happens in Npgsql, but ADO.NET and ODBC state that new requests are queued and no new connections exceeding the maximum pool size are created.

Comment: Npgsql definitely is not supported to open more connections than `Maximum Pool Size` - if that's happening, that's a bug. Note that the maximum applies only to the process - and to the connection string within that process, so if you have two connection strings they are counted as two separate pools (of course, if the app is running twice on the same machine or on different servers, each one has its own internal pool).

If you're convinced that's not the case, can you please provide more information, i.e. Npgsql version, minimal code sample?

Comment: @ShayRojansky, could executing code in a different thread or a separate scope (using `ServiceProvider.CreateScope`) cause the creation of a separate connection pool?

Comment: Ordinarily no - as long as there's one connection string in your application, Npgsql will have one application-global pool.